# Spark hiveContext won't load for Dataframes

Tags: python, apache-spark, dataframe, pyspark

I'm trying to use the 'Window' functions in Spark DataFrames. I understand I need to use HiveContext (which requires Hive). So I built Spark with the following command:

`./make-distribution.sh --name custom-spark --tgz -Phadoop-2.6 -Pyarn -Phive -Phive-thriftserver`

Yet, when I try to call HiveContext from Python, I get the following error:

> > You must build Spark with Hive. Export 'SPARK_HIVE=true' and run build/sbt assembly", Py4JJavaError(u'An error occurred while calling None.org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext.\n', JavaObject id=o264))

When I print details on the Hive error with `sqlContext._get_hive_ctx()`, I get:

> > Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling None.org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext.
> >     : java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.SessionHiveMetaStoreClient
> >         at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.start(SessionState.java:522)
> >         at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.ClientWrapper.(ClientWrapper.scala:171)
> >         at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
> >         at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
> >         at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
> >         at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
> >         at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.IsolatedClientLoader.liftedTree1$1(IsolatedClientLoader.scala:183)
> >         at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.IsolatedClientLoader.(IsolatedClientLoader.scala:179)
> >         at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext.metadataHive$lzycompute(HiveContext.scala:226)
> >         at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext.metadataHive(HiveContext.scala:185)
> >         at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext.setConf(HiveContext.scala:392)
> >         at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext.defaultOverrides(HiveContext.scala:174)
> >         at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext.(HiveContext.scala:177)
> >         at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
> >         at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
> >         at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
> >         at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
> >         at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:234)
> >         at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:379)
> >         at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:214)
> >         at py4j.commands.ConstructorCommand.invokeConstructor(ConstructorCommand.java:79)
> >         at py4j.commands.ConstructorCommand.execute(ConstructorCommand.java:68)
> >         at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:207)
> >         at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
> >     Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.SessionHiveMetaStoreClient
> >         at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.MetaStoreUtils.newInstance(MetaStoreUtils.java:1523)
> >         at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingMetaStoreClient.(RetryingMetaStoreClient.java:86)
> >         at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingMetaStoreClient.getProxy(RetryingMetaStoreClient.java:132)
> >         at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingMetaStoreClient.getProxy(RetryingMetaStoreClient.java:104)
> >         at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.createMetaStoreClient(Hive.java:3005)
> >         at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.getMSC(Hive.java:3024)
> >         at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.start(SessionState.java:503)
> >     23 more
> >     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
> >         at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
> >         at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
> >         at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
> >         at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
> >         at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.MetaStoreUtils.newInstance(MetaStoreUtils.java:1521)
> >     29 more
> >     Caused by: javax.jdo.JDOFatalDataStoreException: Failed to start database 'metastore_db' with class loader org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.IsolatedClientLoader$$anon$1@7ffe486b, see the next exception for details.
> >     NestedThrowables:
> >     java.sql.SQLException: Failed to start database 'metastore_db' with class loader org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.IsolatedClientLoader$$anon$1@7ffe486b, see the next exception for details.
> >         at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.NucleusJDOHelper.getJDOExceptionForNucleusException(NucleusJDOHelper.java:436)
> >         at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.freezeConfiguration(JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.java:788)
> >         at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.createPersistenceManagerFactory(JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.java:333)
> >         at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.getPersistenceManagerFactory(JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.java:202)
> >         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
> >         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
> >         at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> >         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
> >         at javax.jdo.JDOHelper$16.run(JDOHelper.java:1965)
> >         at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
> >         at javax.jdo.JDOHelper.invoke(JDOHelper.java:1960)
> >         at javax.jdo.JDOHelper.invokeGetPersistenceManagerFactoryOnImplementation(JDOHelper.java:1166)
> >         at javax.jdo.JDOHelper.getPersistenceManagerFactory(JDOHelper.java:808)
> >         at javax.jdo.JDOHelper.getPersistenceManagerFactory(JDOHelper.java:701)
> >         at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore.getPMF(ObjectStore.java:365)
> >         at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore.getPersistenceManager(ObjectStore.java:394)
> >         at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore.initialize(ObjectStore.java:291)
> >         at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore.setConf(ObjectStore.java:258)
> >         at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setConf(ReflectionUtils.java:73)
> >         at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:133)
> >         at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RawStoreProxy.(RawStoreProxy.java:57)
> >         at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RawStoreProxy.getProxy(RawStoreProxy.java:66)
> >         at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.newRawStore(HiveMetaStore.java:593)
> >         at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.getMS(HiveMetaStore.java:571)
> >         at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.createDefaultDB(HiveMetaStore.java:624)
> >         at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.init(HiveMetaStore.java:461)
> >         at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingHMSHandler.(RetryingHMSHandler.java:66)
> >         at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingHMSHandler.getProxy(RetryingHMSHandler.java:72)
> >         at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore.newRetryingHMSHandler(HiveMetaStore.java:5762)
> >         at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStoreClient.(HiveMetaStoreClient.java:199)
> >         at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.SessionHiveMetaStoreClient.(SessionHiveMetaStoreClient.java:74)
> >     34 more
> >     Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Failed to start database 'metastore_db' with class loader org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.IsolatedClientLoader$$anon$1@7ffe486b, see the next exception for details.
> >         at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory40.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
> >         at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.Util.newEmbedSQLException(Unknown Source)
> >         at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.Util.seeNextException(Unknown Source)
> >         at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection.bootDatabase(Unknown Source)
> >         at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection.(Unknown Source)
> >         at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection40.(Unknown Source)
> >         at org.apache.derby.jdbc.Driver40.getNewEmbedConnection(Unknown Source)
> >         at org.apache.derby.jdbc.InternalDriver.connect(Unknown Source)
> >         at org.apache.derby.jdbc.Driver20.connect(Unknown Source)
> >         at org.apache.derby.jdbc.AutoloadedDriver.connect(Unknown Source)
> >         at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:571)
> >         at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:187)
> >         at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DriverManagerConnectionFactory.createConnection(DriverManagerConnectionFactory.java:78)
> >         at org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolableConnectionFactory.makeObject(PoolableConnectionFactory.java:582)
> >         at org.apache.commons.pool.impl.GenericObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericObjectPool.java:1148)
> >         at org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolingDataSource.getConnection(PoolingDataSource.java:106)
> >         at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.ConnectionFactoryImpl$ManagedConnectionImpl.getConnection(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:501)
> >         at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.RDBMSStoreManager.(RDBMSStoreManager.java:298)
> >         at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
> >         at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
> >         at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
> >         at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
> >         at org.datanucleus.plugin.NonManagedPluginRegistry.createExecutableExtension(NonManagedPluginRegistry.java:631)
> >         at org.datanucleus.plugin.PluginManager.createExecutableExtension(PluginManager.java:301)
> >         at org.datanucleus.NucleusContext.createStoreManagerForProperties(NucleusContext.java:1187)
> >         at org.datanucleus.NucleusContext.initialise(NucleusContext.java:356)
> >         at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.freezeConfiguration(JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.java:775)
> >     63 more
> >     Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Failed to start database 'metastore_db' with class loader org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.IsolatedClientLoader$$anon$1@7ffe486b, see the next exception for details.
> >         at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
> >         at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory40.wrapArgsForTransportAcrossDRDA(Unknown Source)
> >     90 more
> >     Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Another instance of Derby may have already booted the database /Applications/spark-1.5.2/metastore_db.
> >         at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
> >         at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory40.wrapArgsForTransportAcrossDRDA(Unknown Source)
> >         at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory40.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
> >         at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.Util.generateCsSQLException(Unknown Source)
> >     87 more
> >     Caused by: ERROR XSDB6: Another instance of Derby may have already booted the database /Applications/spark-1.5.2/metastore_db.
> >         at org.apache.derby.iapi.error.StandardException.newException(Unknown Source)
> >         at org.apache.derby.impl.store.raw.data.BaseDataFileFactory.privGetJBMSLockOnDB(Unknown Source)
> >         at org.apache.derby.impl.store.raw.data.BaseDataFileFactory.run(Unknown Source)
> >         at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
> >         at org.apache.derby.impl.store.raw.data.BaseDataFileFactory.getJBMSLockOnDB(Unknown Source)
> >         at org.apache.derby.impl.store.raw.data.BaseDataFileFactory.boot(Unknown Source)
> >         at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.BaseMonitor.boot(Unknown Source)
> >         at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.TopService.bootModule(Unknown Source)
> >         at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.BaseMonitor.startModule(Unknown Source)
> >         at org.apache.derby.iapi.services.monitor.Monitor.bootServiceModule(Unknown Source)
> >         at org.apache.derby.impl.store.raw.RawStore.boot(Unknown Source)
> >         at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.BaseMonitor.boot(Unknown Source)
> >         at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.TopService.bootModule(Unknown Source)
> >         at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.BaseMonitor.startModule(Unknown Source)
> >         at org.apache.derby.iapi.services.monitor.Monitor.bootServiceModule(Unknown Source)
> >         at org.apache.derby.impl.store.access.RAMAccessManager.boot(Unknown Source)
> >         at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.BaseMonitor.boot(Unknown Source)
> >         at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.TopService.bootModule(Unknown Source)
> >         at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.BaseMonitor.startModule(Unknown Source)
> >         at org.apache.derby.iapi.services.monitor.Monitor.bootServiceModule(Unknown Source)
> >         at org.apache.derby.impl.db.BasicDatabase.bootStore(Unknown Source)
> >         at org.apache.derby.impl.db.BasicDatabase.boot(Unknown Source)
> >         at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.BaseMonitor.boot(Unknown Source)
> >         at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.TopService.bootModule(Unknown Source)
> >         at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.BaseMonitor.bootService(Unknown Source)
> >         at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.BaseMonitor.startProviderService(Unknown Source)
> >         at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.BaseMonitor.findProviderAndStartService(Unknown Source)
> >         at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.BaseMonitor.startPersistentService(Unknown Source)
> >         at org.apache.derby.iapi.services.monitor.Monitor.startPersistentService(Unknown Source)

I'm running Spark 1.5.2 and calling it through IPython. For reference, here's my code that generates the error:

```
from __future__ import print_function

import os
import sys
import pandas as pd
import time

from pyspark import SparkConf, SparkContext
from pyspark.sql import HiveContext, SQLContext
from pyspark.sql.types import Row, StructField, StructType, StringType, IntegerType, DoubleType
from pyspark import context
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql.window import Window

from pyspark.sql.functions import *

sc = SparkContext(appName="Bench")
sqlContext = HiveContext(sc)

DATA=

try:
    df = sqlContext.read.load(DATA+"/converted/dataset.parquet", format="parquet") 
    windowSpec = Window.partitionBy('A').orderBy('B')    
    df.select(rank().over(window), min('C').over(window)).show()
    sc.stop()
except Exception, e:
    print(str(e))
    print(sqlContext._get_hive_ctx())
    sc.stop()
```

Answer (score 1):

I found one step is missed(copy hive-site.xml) in your configuration:
http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#hive-tables

> Configuration of Hive is done by placing your hive-site.xml file in conf/. Please note when running the query on a YARN cluster (yarn-cluster mode), the datanucleus jars under the lib_managed/jars directory and hive-site.xml under conf/ directory need to be available on the driver and all executors launched by the YARN cluster. The convenient way to do this is adding them through the --jars option and --file option of the spark-submit command.